# I'm able to ping anything, but it feels as if I didn't have internet

Tags: windows, networking

Something weird happened yesterday

After restarting PC I can enter any site for 5-10minutes and then my internet stops working

I can only ping anything like google.com or 8.8.8.8 and so on, but I cannot enter any site and every program that's using network stops working

it just loads forever

How can I diagnose what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried resetting your router or modem?

Comment: @vssher I just formatted my PC and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can reset your TCP/IP status. Open elevated Command prompt and run `netsh winsock reset && netsh int ip reset && ipconfig /release && ipconfig /renew`. This chain will first reset your Winsock, then TCP/IP stack, then renew DHCP lease. If problem still persists, check if your browser is allowed to access the internet (maybe be blocked by firewall). Flush your DNS cache with command `ipconfig /flushdns` and flush routing table with `netsh interface ip delete destinationcache`.

Comment: Unfortunely nope :/